# Test broken on jenkins but running locally

Tags: linux, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin

we are having such a weird error. Our Tests are running in the local machines (windows) but not running on jenkins (linux).

We get a

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There was an error in the forked process
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
```

I'm being looking for solution and got this info on [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=988977)
or [archive](https://www.mail-archive.com/issues@maven.apache.org/msg98957.html).

Has anybody an idea about this issue and how to solve it?

Thanks

UPDATE

maven-surefire-plugin is also defined in the parent pom.xml for using with cobertura. The Tests are running twice but the second time the tests fails as described above.

I'm defining 2 profiles that are using the surefire-plugin and a surefire plugin definition in the  section.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*SoapUiTest.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <excludes>
                    <!--exclude>**/*.java</exclude -->
                </excludes>
                <additionalClasspathElements>
                   <additionalClasspathElement>${basedir}/src/main/java</additionalClasspathElement>
                </additionalClasspathElements>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>soapUi</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*EntityTest.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*SoapUiTest.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
       </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>integration</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                       <configuration>
                           <excludes>
                               <exclude>**/*EntityTest.java</exclude>
                           </excludes>
                           <includes>
                            <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
                           </includes>
                       </configuration>
                   </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try to execute your tests with `mvn -e test` at the linux command line and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an ussue with cobertura itself (-Dcobertura.test=true). Activating it resolved the Problem.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having similar issue. It might be related to ulimit - number of allowed opened files. ClassLoader needs to open file for loading. Since class is not loaded/available NoClassDefFoundError is thrown on method call.
Check how many files can be opened:

```
ulimit -a
```

To increase number of opened files:

```
ulimit -n NEW_NUMBER
```

In order to change it permanently follow instructions from [this link](http://ithubinfo.blogspot.com/2013/07/how-to-increase-ulimit-open-file-and.html)

> Follow the steps:
>
> vi /etc/security/limits.conf  and add below the mentioned
>
> - soft     nofile         65535
> - hard     nofile         65535

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint but thats will not solve the problem. What occures is that the cobertura and surefire are running both the tests. When running the default-test execution surefire is not finding the classes. Why it does not do it is what I want to know and fix.